# Are back edges mandatory in Ford Fulkerson algorithm?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, flows

Consider the algorithm of Ford Fulkerson where, for each iteration, you add flow along a path equal to the maximum residual capacity along this path.
Does it exist, for every network, a choice of paths such that no "back edge" is used, i.e the only edges used were in the network from the beginning?
I guess it is not the case, but I could not find a counter example...

Comment: It is not hard to prove that there is some set of paths providing a max flow with each path using edges only in the forward direction, but I gather you are asking for a stronger result.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use the primal-dual relationship to find the corresponding answer.